# Import a local library in Choregraphe

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library, choregraphe

I am writing a block's code in choregraphe and I need some functions in numpy and pillow libraries. I installed pillow and numpy in the same folder of the behavior using pip. In Choregraphe Inside the block code i tried:

```
from sys import path
path.append(ALFrameManager.getBehaviorPath(self.behaviorId))
from PIL import Image
from scipy import array, inf
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import shortest_path, csgraph_from_dense
```

and I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

If I comment the line

```
from PIL import Image
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name multiarray
```

I tried to reinstall both the libraries but nothing changes. Where am I wrong? In the same folder there is also a class I wrote but don't have problems importing it, and I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on a robot (which one? Which OS version?), or locally on your computer?

If it's on a robot, chances are the .so files (and other binaries) of the libraries included in your package are not compiled for the right architecture.

Some possibilities:

- Use the numpy that's already on the robot (won't help you with scipy, I don't think it's on the robot, I may be wrong tho) (I wouldn't be surprised if PIL was also already on the robot, I seem to recall seeing it but don't have a handy robot to check)
- In NAOqi 2.5, use the pip already present on the robot; but first you'll need to upgrade it:

> ```
> pip install --user --upgrade pip
> ```

and then

> ```
> /home/nao/.local/bin/pip install --user scipy (or whatever other package you need)
> ```

Then you don't need to package those files in your choregraphe package (but you'll have to do the same procedure on all robots you want to install this to, which may or may not suit your usecase.

Comment: I don't have the robot so I'm just trying to run it on the simulator in Choreographe

Comment: In this case, the problem is the python evaluator used by Choregraphe is embedded and not using the python binary and library from your computer. A very nasty way would be to call the computer python from a python code, using some Popen style command. But's it's very ugly...

Comment: On a choregraphe virtual robot, ALFrameManager.getBehaviorPath probably won't help you much; but in that case you could try appending the actual library paths on your computer to sys.path.